# Sending active workbook as .csv or .xls

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to send my workbook as a .csv or .xls document as attachement to email. Since I'm using a .xlsm document to run my macro the attachment would be a .xlsm document. My workbook should be input for a web application, and i need it to be either .xls or .csv.

Is there any line i could add to my code below to create it into a .csv or .xls document before sending? I don't want to save an extra copy on my computer, just want it to change the document type in the attachement.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .Body = ""
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: you have to make a CSV copy before. You can delete the file after it's sent with `Kill "path and full file name"`

Comment: So just save as a CSV file, add as attachment to the email and then delete it?

Comment: If you only have a one sheet in the book, it would be good to just save a copy of the sheet as CSV, send it and then delete the csv copy. Do you have only one sheet that you are sending? Remember that CSV file only hold 1 sheet.

Comment: To save sheet as CSV: `Sheet1.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV`

Comment: If you're on a windows machine you could always even use the temp folder as the path to save it. This can be accessed using `Environ("TEMP")` Otherwise the code above might fall down if the workbook is not saved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually create a copy of the workbook somewhere in order to change the file type, attach it and send it. You can do this with a function:

```
Function GetCSVCopy() As String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempSheet = ActiveSheet.Copy
    tempName$ = Environ$("TEMP") & "\" & Replace$(wb.Name, ".xlsm", ".csv")
    tempSheet.SaveAs tempName, xlCSV
    tempSheet.Close False
    wb.Activate

    GetCSVCopy = tempName
End Function
```

---

Use like so:

```
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .Body = ""
    attName$ = GetCSVCopy
    .Attachments.Add attName
    .Send
End With

Kill attName '// Remove file after use.
```